# Filter OpenOffice Calc rows by matching if a cell in one column exists in another column with a certain value

Tags: worksheet-function, openoffice, openoffice-calc

Have a question I cant seem to figure out using the filter.

Column A has 1400 rows with 800 additional rows that are duplicates (so 2200 total rows).

Column B has inventory amount for only the last 800 rows of Column A.

I want to filter my data so I only select rows where there is a duplicate value for Column A and my inventory amount in Column B is greater than 0 (i.e. one of those last 800 rows)

Comment: Dunno about Calc, but with Excel you could use the following in a "helper column" (example formula for row 1): `=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,B1>0)`. Then, filter the sheet to only show rows where that column's value is TRUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a array formula, you could use the [**`COUNTIF()`**](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_COUNTIF_function) function to check for duplicates. Assuming this sample data:

[image]

You can add a flag in Column `C` indicating duplicates in Col. `A` using this formula in `C2`, and copying it down:

> `=(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13, A2)>1)`

This results in:

[image]

Now, you can add a second "flag column", combining the boolean value of col `C` with a check for `B>0`:

> `=AND(C2,B2>0)`

Now, we have:

[image]

Of course, you could combine both formulae - the result (again for `row 2`) may look like:

> `=AND((COUNTIF($A$2:$A$13,A2)>1),B2>0)`

As result, you have an additional column with a `TRUE` flag for all rows that are duplicates and have an `amount > 0`. Now, you can apply an `AutoFilter` (Menu "`Date`" -> "`Filter`" -> "`AutoFilter`") and filter for rows with that `TRUE` flag:

[image]

*(tested with LO Calc - should work the same way using OOo Calc).*

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add one column and then use Autofilter after that.

The added column should then contain "flags" for duplicates, if the table starts at line 2 the formula will be:

`=SUM(IF($A$2:$A$9999=A2,1,0))`
*edit: Realized that by adding `>1` at the end here you will get "TRUE" / "FALSE" flags instead. It is up to you.*

and that needs to be entered in the cell with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER
This will make it read with `{` and `}` at the ends as you VIEW the formula in the formula bar.

These cells will contain the COUNT of that value in the column, so: duplicates are >1

Copy the formula to the other lines...  then use the Autofilter features for the remainder of the filtering.

*NOTE: LibreOffice requires a change to the cell contents for re-entering it, add a space at the end*

Comment: I get Err:522 when I try that. I don't see how that would help me. My duplicates are not in a separate column, they are in the SAME column.

Comment: I had ` ; ` in there, changed to ` , ` now did that help?

Comment: ... you didn't have a ';' in your original suggestion?!?    I can't even use =(a2=c2)

Comment: the second suggestion =IF((A2=C2),"DUPE","-")   gives Err:508

Comment: You have some strange Excel then. Have a look above again.

Comment: I'm doing this in OpenOffice Calc

Comment: I'm writing stuff that works in both Excel and LibreOffice Calc (where I try it out as I type). As I have not tried OO-Calc I cannot comment on it. May be you have an older version?

Comment: Just downloaded libreoffice . I have a '1' value for everything.

Comment: Hmm... look for the curly braces, do you have them? Did you enter the formula with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER ?

Comment: how can i enter it into a cell using ctrl+enter+shift? i cant press that and ctrl+v at the same time. I'm lost.

Comment: CTRL-V first, type/change if required, then CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.